# Get preferences in AppWidget Provider

Tags: android, android-widget, preferences, android-preferences

I seem to be having trouble reading preferences from my AppWidgetProvider class. My code works in an Activity, but it does not in an AppWidgetProvider. Here is the code I am using to read back a boolean:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean autoreplyon = settings.getBoolean("autoreplyon", false);
```

However, I get the "The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type widget" error (widget is the name of my AppWidgetProvider class).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getSharedPreferences()`, should you choose to use it, is only available on subclasses of `Context`, like `Activity` or `Service`. `AppWidgetProvider` is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`, which is not a `Context`.

That being said, if you are going to use the `PreferenceScreen` system, or if you are not certain that it's gotta gotta gotta be `getSharedPreferences()`, I would use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` instead. Those are the `SharedPreferences` that `PreferenceScreen`/`PreferenceActivity` will use.

Answer (score 6):

You should have been passed a context in widget's `onUpdate()` method so you can call `context.getSharedPreferences()`.

For per-appwidget preferences, I have used this:

```
public static String getSharedPreferencesNameForAppWidget(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    return context.getPackageName() + "_preferences_" + appWidgetId;
}

public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferencesForAppWidget(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(
        getSharedPreferencesNameForAppWidget(context, appWidgetId), 0);
}
```