# SharedPreferences strage. getSharedPreferences not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Please, help me. I dont know what is wrong with this code:

```
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class WeatherWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

static SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("weather_prefs", 0);

public void onUpdate()
{
    settings.getString("location", "N/A");
}
}
```

In the line "static SharedPreferences..." I get an error:

The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type WeatherWidget

Why its undefined method if its class method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getSharedPreferences` method is not available for an `AppWidgetProvider` because it's not a Context. This link explains a bit more: [Get preferences in AppWidget Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748268/get-preferences-in-appwidget-provider)

Answer (score 4):

You need a Context object to get shared preference reference:

```
// add to WeatherWidget:
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context ctx)
{
    settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences("weather_prefs", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Send the context as a parameter from the activity class to the non-activity class

**In your Activity class:**

```
function_name( getApplicationContext() ); // calling
(or simply)
function_name( this ); // calling
```

**In your Non Activity class:** (where no context exists)

```
public void fun_name(Context ctx)
{
    settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to get shared preferences object in AppWidgetProvider:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        if (prefs == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("prefs");
prefs.getInt(....);
```